# how to create nicer variable interface in python class

Tags: python, class, variables, getter-setter

I want a variable to do more than just be set when I set it.
and the interface to be as clean as possible.

short: what I'd want:

```
# have class with a variable that I can access:
print myInstance.var
42
# change the variable
myInstance.var = 23
# have the change kick off another method:
self.var was changed: 23!!
```

hmm.. so what I can do: Use the variable and a setter method:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1
        print( 'self.var is: ' + str(self.var) )
    def setVar(self, value):
        self.var = value
        print( 'self.var changed: ' + str(self.var) )

t = Test()
self.var is: 1

# so I have t.var at hand:
print t.var
1

# and change it this way
t.setVar(5)
self.var changed: 5
```

But then i have 2 different things to work with..
Ok I could make a method to interact with the var:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1
        print( 'self.var is: ' + str(self.var) )
    def method(self, value=None):
        if value == None:
            return self.var
        self.var = value
        print( 'self.var changed: ' + str(self.var) )

t = Test()
self.var is: 1
# to get the value then:
print t.method()
1
# to set it:
t.method(4)
self.var changed: 4
# and verifiy:
print t.method()
4
```

This is nice already. I've seen it in different post on other languages. but I dunno. Is there a be better solution in python?!?

Maybe I'm paranoid but but to me it'd just feel nicer to just do `t.var = 5` and have something kicked off too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want python Properties.  Check [this out](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/ChrisBeaumont/5758381/raw/descriptor_writeup.ipynb).  Something like:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self._var = 1

    @property
    def var(self):
        return self._var

    @var.setter
    def var(self, value):
        # add stuff here that you want to happen on var assignment
        self._var = value
```

Comment: Thank you too @Xephryous ! Thats a great link too! just checked it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [property](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property). Note that if the setter method is expensive, it's better to use a method. People expect attribute access to be fast.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._var = None
    @property
    def var(self):
        return self._var
    @var.setter
    def var(self, whatever):
        self._var = whatever
        do_whatever()

x = Foo()
print x.var # prints None
x.var = 2   # sets x.var and does whatever
```

Comment: Yea thats what I thought. But its for ui stuff so the calls are rather rare! Thanks very much. For the remark too!